# How is it that both my if and else statements are executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code is working just fine - but both my if and else statements are executing, which I've never seen before and cannot understand:

```
function submit(total_lines) {

  total_lines   = total_lines;
  completed_lines         = 0;   

  /* create one line at a time... */
  for (i=0;i<total_lines;i++) {    

    color      = $('#color_' + i).val();
    qty        = $('#qty_' + i).val();

    console.log("starting line " + completed_lines);        

    if ( color && qty ) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',                                                       
        url: '/submit_line.php',              
        data: { color:color, qty:qty },
        success:function(data){                                                                                                                                      
          console.log("Line " + completed_lines + " was successfull");              
          completed_lines++;
        }                                                
      }); //close ajax         
    } else {
       console.log("Line " + completed_lines + " was not successfull. color = " + color + " and qty = " + qty);          
       toastr.error("Color and quantity are both required fields.");
    }  
  }

  setTimeout(function(){
    toastr.success("All done! ..."); 
    $('#add_something_footer').html('<div class="footer_buttons_holder"><div onclick="close_swal()" class="footer_cancel_button">CLOSE</div></div>');     
  }, 5000);

}
```

For each iteration of `i`, The `submit_line.php` is executing, as it should, but I'm also getting the `toastr.error` line in my `else` statement executing.  How is this possible - `color` and `qty` both exist, so the primary part of the `if` statement is executing.. I don't believe my syntax is bad anywhere, (otherwise nothing would execute...).  I'm confused...

## Edit

Updated the OP to reference console.log statements.

Here's my console.log

```
Object {type: "info", iconClass: "toast-info", message: "Submitting quotes...", optionsOverride: undefined, title: undefined}
5VM7093:699 starting line 0
VM7093:712 Line 0 was not successfull. color = undefined and quantity = undefined
toastr_qt.js:227 Object {type: "error", iconClass: "toast-error", message: "Color and quantity are both required fields", optionsOverride: undefined, title: undefined}
VM7093:699 starting line 0
VM7093:712 Line 0 was not successfull. color = undefined and quantity = undefined
toastr_qt.js:227 Object {type: "error", iconClass: "toast-error", message: "Color and quantity are both required fields", optionsOverride: undefined, title: undefined}
VM7093:699 starting line 0
VM7093:712 Line 0 was not successfull. color = undefined and quantity = undefined
toastr_qt.js:227 Object {type: "error", iconClass: "toast-error", message: "Color and quantity are both required fields", optionsOverride: undefined, title: undefined}
VM7093:699 starting line 0
VM7093:712 Line 0 was not successfull. color = undefined and quantity = undefined
toastr_qt.js:227 Object {type: "error", iconClass: "toast-error", message: "Color and quantity are both required fields.", optionsOverride: undefined, title: undefined}
VM7093:699 starting line 0
VM7093:712 Line 0 was not successfull. color = undefined and quantity = undefined
toastr_qt.js:227 Object {type: "error", iconClass: "toast-error", message: "Color and quantity are both required fields.", optionsOverride: undefined, title: undefined}
VM7093:708 Line 1 was successfull
VM7093:708 Line 2 was successfull
VM7093:708 Line 3 was successfull
VM7093:708 Line 4 was successfull
toastr_qt.js:227 Object {type: "success", iconClass: "toast-success", message: "All done!", optionsOverride: undefined, title: undefined}
```

The fact that in my console - all lines are going through the `else` statement FIRST, as the variables are undefined, then passing again through the regular `if` statement because they ARE defined is the thing that is confusing me.  How can the variable be `undefined` if I define it directly above the `ajax` line?

Comment: Are you sure that both `color` and `qty` have truthy values for every single iteration?

Comment: can you create a plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: can you add a console.log() in your ajax success, to see how many times that gets called relative to the errors. I don't think if and else are called at the same time.

Comment: @krillgar - if the ID elements are not filled in with something, they return as false - I've used this syntax tons of times for different pages. Either way, I'm not sure how both the if and else could trigger based on the truthiness of the variable?

Comment: @BrianPowell most likely not triggered at the same time but on different iteration of the `for` loop. use a `console.log()` to observe the state of these variable in each iteration

Comment: I think the behaviour you are seeing is a red-herring (false alarm).  There is also some context missing, like the HTML that is being referenced.  I would also encourage you to change your if condition to be more type specific.  It might help to console.log the values of qty and color

Comment: The data line looks a bit suspect: `data: { color:color, qty_qty },`, maybe it should be `data: { color:color, qty:qty },`? Although I'm not sure that this would cause the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: @sleeyuen - sorry - that was actually just a typo here... my actual code has like 40 variables, so I just changed it to color & qty to make it easier to read, but yes - that would fail in actual code. thanks!

Comment: color      = $('#color_0').val(); or
    qty        = $('#qty_0').val();
is not defined, start your loop at 1 maybe?

Comment: You're only incrementing `completed_lines` on a success, meaning if 5 fail in a row, they'll all return the same thing for `"Line " + completed_lines + " was not successful.";` You're not getting the line that failed, you're just getting `last successful iteration + 1`.

Comment: No - I'm sure my ID elements start at 0.  `<input class="as_multi_input_lg form-control-small" value="BLUE" id="color_0">`

Comment: then what's the value for $('#qty_0').val()? add console.log(color);console.log(qty); to the else clause, you will see the problem. no mysterious

Comment: my `total_lines` variable was incorrect - the code is working just fine - but that variable was too big, so I was executing the first 4 lines, and it was working fine, THEN I was executing the next 4 lines, which referenced id elements that did not exist, so the variable was undefined, and it was triggering the else statement.  We're all good here!  Sorry to waste everyone's time :)